# Is it appropriate to remove a privelege from my younger brother for bad behavior?

Tags: conflicts, parenting

I own a game that my younger brother who is 10 enjoys playing. Because he enjoys complaining about things I've been allowing him to use some functions on his own time to play it. But this morning he decided to yell at me when I gave him some helpful advice and after he left for the bus I removed his ability to use some of the game. Because the game is mine I feel like I should be able to do that but the device that the game is being used on is not mine and I'm not supposed to be "parenting" him which is a whole other can of worms. My question is **"Should I remove a privelege from my younger sibling for reacting rudely if it's not my place to parent him but the privelege is mine to give?**

Comment: Hi @SlothsAndMe The purpose of this site is to help you to choose what to say or do according to the decision you have already taken. But not regarding about the decision you must take in first place. Maybe you can adjust your question to let us help you.

Comment: @Santiago I'm more looking for if I need to remedy my actions or not :D thanks for informing me.

Comment: We can't really tell you what you *should* do, but when you determine your course of action, we can help you convey the decision to your younger brother. For example, if you decide to stick to your decision, we can suggest ways to constructively let him know that what he did was inappropriate. Or if you decide to remedy the situation, we can help you figure out how to apologize and restore friendship. Adjust your question to whatever you decide, and we will go from there! Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Maybe you can post this in Parenting.StackExchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As tempting as it can be respond this way to a negative interaction, reprisal is rarely helpful (in the adult world reprisal can quickly lead to job loss). Instead it's better to try to deal with the situation directly rather than attack something else they care about.

When you've both cooled off you can ask why he yelled at you and try to understand his point of view. Explain to him that upsetting him wasn't your intent and that you didn't appreciate him yelling. With any luck this will allow the two of you to come to some understanding and find some compromise in case a similar situation comes up.